# Setting a field readonly rather than invisible from hook_field_access()?

Tags: entities, hooks

I have a field that should not be visible when editing, in certain cases (depending on node state and user).
It works fine using `hook_field_access()`:

```
function mymodule_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ( ...conditions on $entity_type, $entity->type, $field['field_name'], $op...) {
    // → $op=='edit' && isset($entity->nid) so only when modifying existing content
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

As said it works fine, and the field is not displayed at all when access is not granted.

But in some particular conditions I would like to let the field visible but readonly (grey-ed, or anything preventing to modify it) rather than hiding it.

I tried to return TRUE and before to set according attributes to the field, but until now I failed to make it works as expected. What I tested:

```
$tmp = mode_load($entity->nid);
$tmp->my_field['#attributes'] = array('readonly' => 'readonly'); // also tried to use 'disabled')
node_save($tmp);
```

I also tried:

```
$tmp->my_field['#disabled'] = true;
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards.

Comment: You need to alter this field at display or on edit form ?

Comment: On edit. My conditions to hide the field is for preventing some users in some conditions to edit this field. But in some other cases I would like them to be able to see the field value when editing, but not to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that :

Replace `FORM_ID` with the real form ID.

```
function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  if(!user_access(ADMIN_USER)){
      $form['your_field_name']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    }

    $form['your_field_name']['#access'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This example does (part of) the trick. But in my particular case I allow the field with more complex criteria. For example the field is writable at creation (`($op=='edit') && isset($entity->nid)` to restrict only on existing content). Is it possible from `form-alter` to get similar informations than from `field_access`?

Comment: Hmm… Yes I can: `$node = $form_state['node']; if (!isset($node->nid) or isset($node->is_new)) { ...this is a node creation... }`.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify for me: is it whatever possible to alter a field from `field_access()`?

Comment: If you want to alter the form on node/add/article use : `function MYMODULE_node_article_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)` and if you want to alter the form on node/{id}/edit use : `function MYMODULE_node_article_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)`

Comment: `field_access` can't alter your field, return TRUE if the operation is allowed, and FALSE if the operation is denied.